# Round vertices in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let drawingCanvas = document.getElementById("smile");
  if (drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
    let cx = drawingCanvas.getContext("2d");

    const dots = [
      { id: 0, x: 0, y: 645 },
      { id: 1, x: 42, y: 686 },
      { id: 2, x: 37, y: 849 },
      { id: 3, x: 263, y: 849 },
      { id: 4, x: 299, y: 707 },
      { id: 5, x: 268, y: 404 },
      { id: 6, x: 241, y: 115 },
      { id: 7, x: 63, y: 115 },
      { id: 8, x: 42, y: 404 },
    ];

    cx.beginPath();
    cx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);
    dots.forEach((dot) => {
      cx.lineTo(dot.x, dot.y);
    });
    cx.fill();
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="smile" height=900 width=300></canvas>
```

**and this result:**

[image: pic]

I need to make the lines smoother, the figure is built on points, so at the point of connection of lines (vertices) sharp corners

[image: pic]

**expecting result:**
[image: pic]

I tried bezier curves, but this dont help

Comment: Can you share you bezier attempt? There's no hope of the provided code producing rounded corners, so while it's helpful to see, it's not really an attempt.

Comment: If it's a one time project for this shape only - then you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc to make round corners